# product purchase limit according to membership in Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set a product purchase limit according to membership.

Example: If user A will purchase **"Membership 1"** so He/she will able to choose 2 products from all products.

or

If user A will purchase **"Membership 2"** so He/she will able to choose 4 products from all products.

and for that, I am using https://www.skyverge.com/blog/limiting-members-to-one-membership-with-woocommerce-memberships/ this.

I still not succeed.

Comment: Hey @aditya did you find the solution ? I am also looking for this.

Comment: I did not find the solution yet.

Comment: you can try a plugin https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/groups-woocommerce/memberships/selling-time-limited-memberships/ you can limit person according to time.